# Openstack VM AlmaLinux OS 9.3-Multiple subnet NIC not working

Tags: linux-networking, openstack, iproute2, openstack-neutron

I have situation to migrate Centos 7.9 to Almalinux 9.3 VM. Everything is working after migration and i have problem with Openstack Multi NIC not working in different subnet in AlmaLinux 9.3 OS.

eth0 as 20.100.16.0/24 different VLAN-2016
eth1 as 20.100.20.0/24 Different VLAN-2020

i have assigned both eth0 and eth1 in AlmaLinux OS. But only one network i.e eth0 is working.

```
**ip link** 

default via 20.100.16.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 20.100.16.35 metric 100
default via 20.100.20.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 20.100.20.35 metric 101
20.100.16.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 20.100.16.35 metric 100
20.100.20.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 20.100.20.35 metric 101
```

```
**route -n**

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         20.100.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         20.100.20.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
20.100.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
20.100.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1

     ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:2e:d2:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3
    altname ens3
    inet 20.100.16.35/24 brd 20.100.16.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 85248sec preferred_lft 85248sec
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe2e:d2a6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:d1:5b:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s4
    altname ens4
    inet 20.100.20.35/24 brd 20.100.20.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 85248sec preferred_lft 85248sec
    inet6 fe80::30ed:b1cc:291b:64f6/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

i used tcpdump in order to check request and reply

When i hit eth1 interface IP the request hits goes to the G/W via 10.100.16.1 eth0 receives and reply getting from eth1 and i suspected Openstack Neutron port security is enabled the i have disabled both **port_security_enabled :Flase. For these VM Security group not added i.e Egress and Ingress rule **

***eth0***

Openstack port list | grep 20.100.16.35

```
neutron port-update **67af6277-b065-451d-b448-4063ec2c19ae**  --port_security_enabled=False
```

***eth1***

Openstack port list | grep 20.100.20.35

```
neutron port-update **36af6277-k034-653d-c998-6063ec2c45ae**  --port_security_enabled=False
```

After disabling i can see the both network are reachable outside.

*In Previously In Openstack VM Centos 7.9 is working with static route with Multiple NIC in different subnet(**No Changes in Openstack Neutron Port security.its applied with egress & ingress rules**). Same applied to AlmaLinux but here in AlmaLinux 9.3 static route was not working. However i have Nutanix AHV hypervisor there is no issues it default after attaching the different sub-net to the VM it working as expected without any static routes.*

**Openstack Queen Plugin Type : Flat Network**

Please help me out what went wrong here ? ? i want use Openstack neutron port with security group for AlmaLinux 9.3

*****Note :** these same issues occurred with Rocky 9.3 and Oracle Linux 9.3 VMs  in Openstack Hypervisor***

```
SYSCTL.CONF
**cat /etc/sysctl.conf**

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.arp_filter = 1
```